# What is the OLE cache?

Tags: ibm-doors

In the DXL manual, there are several functions that support grabbing the rich text along with OLE objects embedded in the rich text, they are richTextWithOle and richTextWithOleNoCache. In the description of these function the only difference is that one clears the OLE cache. Can anyone explain what this means?

I tried keeping task manager open and monitoring the memory usage, but it didn't seem to make much of a difference. Didn't see anything in the manual either explaining what an OLE cache is.

Comment: There are other reasons for emptying a cache than just to free-up memory: such as forcing a cache invalidation because data is known to be stale, for example. The memory usage of a process on Windows will only go down if a process actively returns that memory to the OS - unless that system is designed to return memory to the OS when the cache is cleared then you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Programs often don't return memory to the OS if they manage their own memory anyway because returning individual pages makes it harder to deal with memory fragmentation.